# z-index does not locate div ontop of the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="centered"  >
        <div class="vinyl" id="vinyl1" style="z-index:2;"></div>
         <div style="z-index:5;">
          <img src="images/center-image.png"/>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<style>
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -230px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}
</style>
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('vinyl1');
var property = getTransformProperty(div);
if (property) {
    var d = 0;
    setInterval(
        function () {
            div.style[property] = 'rotate(' + (d++ % 360) + 'deg)';
        },
        100
    );
}
</script>
```

As you see, div with id vinyl1 rotates. 
However, I would like inside to locate in the center of that div, a static div with a static image. (in the demo it's under the div, and has  the number 360 on it)
I tried to put z-index.

1. z-index does not work and it still shows it below
2. how can I locate the image exactly in the center?

You can see the demo [here](http://www.360andbeyond.co.il/index1.php).

Comment: Static positioned elements aren't affected by their z-index property. I.e. you have to change the positioning to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: Looks like the child `<div>` of `.centered` need `.position: fixed` of their own.  `.centered div {position:fixed;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should place the div containing the 360 image logo inside the vinyl div.

Like this:

```
<div class="vinyl" id="vinyl1" style="z-index:2;">
    <div style="z-index:5;">
       <img src="images/center-image.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add position: relative; to vinyl div and position: absolute to div inside it.

**EDIT**

Though you wanted them to rotate together. If you don't want them to rotate together place it outside again. Not sure about rest of the markup but this should do the trick than. Create another container inside your centered div and give it position relative. Leave vinyl div with normal positioning and add position absolute to the div containing the image.

Something like this:

```
<div class="extra_wrap">
    <div class="vinyl" id="vinyl1" style="z-index:2;"></div>
    <div class="image_holder" style="z-index:5;">
       <img src="images/center-image.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.extra_wrap {position: relative;}

.image_holder {position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 150px;}
```

And of course add top and left values for image_holder div to position it in the center.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's not working. See here: http://www.360andbeyond.co.il/index1.php now they rotate together :(

Comment: Regarding add top and left values - I don't want to add it - since I would like it to be in relative to the screen size. So I need it to be centered not with fixed numbers

Comment: It will be centered inside the circle. That is why I suggested to add a relative wrapper around the circle and the image. That means that image_holder is considering that extra_wrap as a parent div. And that div is inside the one you centered with percentages.

Comment: I tried again - http://www.360andbeyond.co.il/index1.php but it doesn't work. I didn't add top and left values for image_holder - do I need to add? if so- what?

Comment: Yes. Try adding left: 150px; top: 150px; to the .image_holder

Comment: thanks. worked. please add the left and top to your answer for future programmers